# bypass journald for uWSGI application?

Tags: uwsgi, centos7, systemd

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to bypass journald for a uWSGI application we're running. We need it to go to rsyslog, which it is, but it's logging a lot and I would like for it not to spam journald. Anyone know if that's possible? We're using centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is not to load the imjournal module in rsyslog and forward all journald to syslog.

in /etc/systemd/journald.conf:

```
ForwardToSyslog=yes
```

in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
#$ModLoad imjournal
```

Seems to keep syslog flowing and the access logs are no longer flooding journald.

Comment: Referring to RHEL7: If you skip loading imjournal and configure journald to use `ForwardToSyslog=yes`, you also need to set `$OmitLocalLogging off` in rsyslog.conf. If you do all that, you still haven't solved your problem -- everything will still go through journald first. I'm curious how you tested it without coming to that conclusion ... hmmm. I'll write up an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- If final destination is local: you can configure the wsgi app to log directly to rsyslog via a custom log socket
- If final destination is remote and you don't care about storing locally: configure the wsgi app to log directly to remote system via udp/tcp

Both of the above options can be implemented thanks to the enhanced version of `logger` available in RHEL7's util-linux package (it added `--socket`, `--udp`, `--server`, `--port`). Example:

```
~]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/httpd-socket.conf
$AddUnixListenSocket /run/httpd-log0.sock
local0.* /var/log/httpd/mywsgiapp.log
& stop

~]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/00-myvhost.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName r72.example.com
  ServerAlias r72
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t httpd -u /run/httpd-log.sock -p local0.info" common
  ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t httpd -u /run/httpd-log.sock -p local0.error"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you can use the latest rsyslog from upstream, you can even configure that custom socket to go straight into its own ruleset + queue for better performance and easier configurability of filtering (assuming you even want to do filtering).